# How to get whether PointText is hit or not using hitTest in paper.js

Tags: javascript, paperjs

I am using paper.js. I have written some text using PointText on canvas. Now I want to select that text by double click.

For this I used hitTest but it tells me only for stroke and segments, not for PointText.

**code :**

```
var hit = scope.project.hitTest(e.point, {

            segments : true,
            stroke : true,
            fill : true,
            tolerance : 5,
            type : 'PointText'

        });

        scope.project.activeLayer.selected = false;

        if (hit && hit.item && hit.item._index > 0) {
            var it=hit.type
            alert(it)

            hit.item.selected = true;
        }
```

Please help me to find solution!

Comment: Have you tried using `TextItem`instead of `PointText`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HitTest on PointText was recently fixed.  Are you using the latest version?

Comment: After using latest version, it worked. But clippping property is not working with latest version while it was working with older version

Comment: If you want help on the clipping, ask a question about it.